optional argument position
inspired by the post Newcommand with optional argument and ifthenelse. float point places can be controled by following code as well. Is it possible to modify the syntax optional argument position such that \test{pi}[4] be valid instead of \test[4]{pi} ?
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\test}[2][]{%
\def\FirstArg{#1}
  \ifx\FirstArg\empty
    \fpeval{#2}% if #1 is empty
    \else
    \fpeval{round(#2,#1)}% if #2 is not empty
  \fi
}

\begin{document}


\test{pi}

\test[4]{pi}

\end{document}


well, of course, that is the standard way the kernel tests for optional arguments e.g. see the definition of \@dblarg, for example. but notice those are almost always followed by mandatory arguments.

the fact that a package does X does not mean X is not a bad idea or that you should compound its errors. this is true even of very good packages. I am not familiar with numerica. all I can tell you is that the syntax you are asking for has inherent limitations due to the way TeX works. i.e. you can make it work within constraints, if you really want to, but you will have an easier time and greater flexibility if you don't. I have no idea why it would be more convenient to type {a}[b] than [b]{a} but such reasons are better taken up with your editor.

@cfr thanks. {a}[b] is more convenient for me at present . I would modify my editor to handle [b]{a} .

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\test@i{#1}}{\fpeval{#1}}%
}
\def\test@i#1[#2]{%
  \fpeval{round(#1, #2)}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\test{pi}

\test{pi}[5]

\end{document}


Yes. And where's the advantage over \NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mo}{...}?

Really outdated method, because there's a much better one.

@xcn: You still have a spurious space in your \def.

@Werner where should I add a space, could you give an example ? I thought the problem was to expand \def argument so that it stores the \fpeval result.

@xcn: Look at this difference.

@Werner  much appreciated for your help.  One more thing , Do you think if it is necessary to expand \def argument so that it stores the \fpeval result ?

@xcn: It depends on your use case. If you want to use it in calculations, then sure. If you just want to set it in text, then it's not necessary.

If you don't need it to be expandable, you can use \NewDocumentCommand:
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}
  {%
    \fpeval{round(#1,#2)}% if optional argument follows
  }{%
    \fpeval{#1}% if no optional argument
  }%
}

You would find you got along better if you read the documentation rather than picking up bits of fragmentary code piecemeal. usrguide.pdf and clsguide.pdf would reward your attention.
Note that there are limitations when using optional arguments like this. You should have compelling reason to design this kind of counterintuitive syntax in any case, but there are also technical pitfalls you should ensure you are aware of, especially if you are considering inflicting this on other people.

@xcn perhaps, but you already have very similar examples, so all you need from the docs is whether you can use om rather than mo in the argument specification.

I understand this point, it says "The last argument (if any are present) must be one of the mandatory types m, r, R, l or u. "

@xcn for \NewExpandableDocumentCommand, yes; not for \NewDocumentCommand. as I said, {}[] rather than []{} means accepting reduced flexibility and additional limitations.
